# Call method from another class into loop inside calling class

Tags: java, loops, optimization, methods, calling-convention

I have a class `X` where I have methods `A` and `B`.

I have a class `Y` where I have loop as below

Is it ideal to call method inside another class inside for loop or is there any ideal way of doing this? please help.

```
public class X {
    public void A() {
    }
    public void B() {
    }
}

public Class Y {
    public void C() {

        for(int i=0; i<0; i++) {
            new ClassX.A()
            .B();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adjust your loop condiiton; `0` is not less than `0` so your loop would not be entered. Next, you need an instance of `X` to invoke `A` and `B` on. You could instantiate one before your loop like

```
public class Y {
    public void C() {
        X x = new X();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.A();
            x.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Or pass the `X` into `C` like

```
public class Y {
    public void C(X x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.A();
            x.B();
        }
    }
}
```

**or** make it an instance field and construct `Y` with it like

```
public class Y {
    private X x;
    public Y(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void C() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.A();
            x.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, by convention, Java method names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Frisch: Thanks for your answer.I have a doubt here as to y we create new mtd Y inside class C..Are we instantiating X class insideY, by making Y as constructor?

Comment: **No**. We are passing an already instantiated `X` reference to `Y` (when `Y` is constructed).

Comment: I tried this last soln.But i donot get hold of the referenced class.Instead i get null pointer. I added this in class Y and created class X like the bleow::

                                                                                                                          private static X x; //line inside class Y

My class X looks like this::::::::::::::::::::::
public class X {
    public void A() {
    System.out.print("jzxhckjh");
    return;
    }
    public void B() {
    System.out.print("jzxhckjh");
    return;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You realize that your loop will never run? That is not a good way to code...

```
for(int i=0;i<0;i++){
```

if I starts at 0 , and you go up. I will never be less than 0.

What are you trying to accomplish with class Y and class X? You can't just ask if its optimal and not provide any reasoning for what you're doing.

Comment: Oops sorry I meant that, I have been up since 6AM yesterday, its been like 30 hours. Pardon my mistake.